# Error Invoking Maven

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to invoke maven from a Java class.

My code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.xml.ws.spi.Invoker;

import org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.DefaultInvocationRequest;
import org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.DefaultInvoker;
import org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.InvocationRequest;
import org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.MavenInvocationException;

public class MavenProjectBuilder implements ProjectBuilder{

    public void BuildProject(String buildPath, String bugID) {

        InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
        request.setPomFile(new File(buildPath));
        request.setGoals(Arrays.asList( "clean", "install" ));

        DefaultInvoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();

        try {
            invoker.execute(request);
        } catch (MavenInvocationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Which returns the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/util/cli/StreamConsumer
    at autoEvoSuite.MavenProjectBuilder.BuildProject(MavenProjectBuilder.java:21)
    at autoEvoSuite.Main.<init>(Main.java:110)
    at tests.GeneralTest.main(GeneralTest.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.StreamConsumer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

I did some research and found out it could be a missing dependency, but shouldn't Maven automatically download all missing ones?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the below dependency is present in your POM.xml, until the dependency is defined in you pom file that jar will not be downloaded to your local repository.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
  <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried DarioP's code with a POM packaging project and it worked like a charm without this dependency - after removing `implements ProjectBuilder` since I didn't find where this comes from.